# How do I save cells just pasted over?

Tags: vba

I am working on a change management. I have good, robust code for single cell changes with old and new target values. for pasting a range, however, it is more complicated. for instance, if i copy range A1:A5 and paste to B1, how do i save the previous values in B1:B5, saving B1 is easy, the rest is beyond me.

Comment: "I have good, robust code" posting your current code is always a good first step toward getting useful responses.

Comment: The code I have ins't relevant to question, of how to save a ranges old values, but to your point i could have been more concise. If you care curious on how i solved that problem then I can send it to you, but it is probably too large to post.

Comment: where are you saving to? ...you can save into a variant variable `dim aaa as variant`  `aaa = range("b1:b5").value`  ... do not paste, use assignment, like so  `range("b1:b5") = range("a1:a5").value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar, the method was fairly simple, when something is pasted it is selected, save the selection.address into a range variable.

Then save each cell's contents to string variables.

then undo the paste.

then copy out the now restored contents of the range variable to wherever you want for backup purposes.

then write back the variables with the originally pasted values over the top.

Set the code to run on a worksheet change event and you are all good. Obviously you need to put in some code to detect that only certain areas are in the target so the event doesn't go bananas and don't forget to turn the events off whilst you do you stuff then back on after.

Comment: I had written it out as this, i was phishing for a different solution, thank you.

Comment: can you please share how you did " save each cell's contents to string variables."?